# Pagination for Multi value Entity Reference fields

Tags: 8

I have added an Entity Reference type (Taxonomy Term) to the User Entity.  It is a multi-value field so that any number of taxonomy terms can have the reference.
[image: Field settings page]
[image: User custom field]
Now I am using the following code to get the referenced entities for the current user.

```php
/** @var \Drupal\user\Entity\User $user */
$user = $this->userStorage->load($this->currentUser->id());

/** @var /Drupal\Core\Field\EntityReferenceFieldItemList $myMagazineReferenceItemList */
$myMagazineReferenceItemList = $user->get('field_my_magazines');

/** @var \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term $myMagazine */
foreach ($myMagazineReferenceItemList->referencedEntities() as $key => $myMagazine) {
    // Create an array of taxonomy terms
}
```

I am able to get all the entity-reference-list in `$myMagazineReferenceItemList`. But **can I use pagination for this?** I am using the code in a REST endpoint, so I would like to make the result paginated. Is there any right-approach for this?

Should I explicitly need to use delta explicitly and build pagination?

Comment: If someone is downvoting the question that is completely fine, only if they are providing an appropriate comments along. How I should know what went wrong with the question?

Comment: Does it have to be a code solution? You could build views for this and control it through Views pagination, even export REST.

Comment: I have used views for similar kind of thing in another place with pagination. ```// Using Views
      $webzineView = Views::getView('rest_api_magazine_homepage');
      $webzineView->get_total_rows = true;
      $webzineView->setCurrentPage($currentPage);
      $webzineView->setItemsPerPage($itemsPerPage);
      $webzineView->execute();```

I am now trying to do all this in code. I don't know is there any pagination helpers are available. If that is not good approach, then can you please explain whether I can use Context Filter for current User and use the view itself.

Comment: Yes, you can create the User type Views, add the taxonomy field and under its Multivalue settings make them show each in its own row. Then set up pagination the way you like, and add the Contextual filter for the User ID and set it to Provide default value sth like Logged in user. Alternatively you can start with Taxonomy term type, add Relationship to user and setup User ID contextual, but I think that performance is worse this way.

Comment: Thanks @prkos. In the first way, by creating user type views the pagination is applied to users right? I am not sure the pagination can be applied to the reference field items (taxonomy terms) of a single user.

Comment: However, the second approach works as expected. Thank you @prkos

Comment: In the first example, yes the base type is User, and you set Pagination in that Views for the entire Views, meaning they apply to users, but you can remove all fields but the Taxonomy term, and if you make that field show values in separate rows, pagination will apply to them, to the taxonomy terms!